# Need help in using a different root for a location in NGINX

Tags: nginx, directive

I have a site configuration pointing to /var/www for a domain (https://somedomain.com/) but I want a location /clientfolder to be redirected to /home/clientfolder/website/

My issue is whenever a request comes in, such as https://somedomain.com/clientfolder/index.html the daemon is looking for a file at /home/clientfolder/website/clientfolder/index.html

So I tried to use the rewrite directive:

```
location /clientfolder {
    rewrite ^/clientfolder/(.*)$ /$1 last;
    root /home/clientfolder/website
}
```

But now https://somedomain.com/clientfolder/index.html loads the file at /var/www/index.html

Is there another directive than rewrite that would allow me to strip the "clientfolder" from the file path if the /clientfolder location was matched?

---

Update: I managed to get this to work, but it feels totally wrong:

```
location /clientfolder/website {
    root /home;
}
location /clientfolder {
    rewrite ^/clientfolder/(.*)$ /clientfolder/website/$1;
}
```

Comment: Your first version would have worked if you used `rewrite...break;` instead. But `alias` is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If URIs beginning with `/clientfolder` are located in `/home/clientfolder/website`, you should use an `alias` directive.

For example:

```
location /clientfolder {
    alias /home/clientfolder/website;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.